# Why does incorrect type affinity on a foreign key column makes joins very slow in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, types, foreign-keys

In our application, we are tracking manufactured components with an alphanumeric serial number, which gives us a natural key. As you might expect, the type affinity we chose was `TEXT`. These components are central to the application, so there are many tables linked through foreign key relationships on this serial number.

On one particular table, the type affinity of the serial number `FOREIGN KEY` column was incorrectly declared as `INTEGER`. Due to the flexibility of the type affinity system, this never showed up as an issue because we were able to `INSERT` `TEXT` values into the column with no problem. Everything seemed to be working fine.

As the database grew modestly, some queries became very slow, in the order of seconds on a modern PC. After making sure that all relevant columns were already automatically indexed due to `FOREIGN KEY` and `PRIMARY KEY` declarations, I found the culprit. After changing the type affinity on the bad table from `INTEGER` to `TEXT`*, the slow query which joined on that table sped up by two orders of magnitude.

I'm happy enough with the end result, but I'd quite like to know why this happened? Was SQLite building a different type of index under the hood due to the declared type affinity? Did the difference in type affinity in the comparison prevent the query from using the index? Was there some unnecessary type conversion going on which was slowing things down?

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pcb_units (
    serial_no TEXT NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (serial_no)
);

CREATE TABLE assembly_pcb_units (
    pcb_serial_no INTEGER NOT NULL,    -- This is the bad column
    assembly_serial_no TEXT NOT NULL,
    added_time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    added_by TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pcb_in_one_assembly_only
        UNIQUE(pcb_serial_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (assembly_serial_no)
        REFERENCES assembly_units(assembly_serial_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (pcb_serial_no)
        REFERENCES pcb_units(serial_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (added_by)
        REFERENCES sti_users(user_id)
);
```

<sub>* I really wish SQLite supported ALTER TABLE. As it was, I had to disable foreign key constraints, drop the table, recreate it, then reinsert all the rows.</sub>

Comment: Please show an example database schema.

Comment: Added the example schema.

Comment: A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not add any index. Please show the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output of the query for both old and new table.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I don't know where I got the idea that they did. Even without the indexes on the foreign keys, my queries are running in quite reasonable time at the moment. I guess I'll be adding some indexes on the child keys and seeing what kind of difference that makes too..

Comment: Actually, I've changed my mind. The documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says that there are no automatic indexes, but it seems like there actually are: SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE '%autoindex%';

Comment: Automatic indexes are created for UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the demo below, the column type mismatch prevents the use of both indexes (see the SCAN TABLE parent), but strangely enough, only when the WHERE clause is on the child_int side. This explains why your queries were slower.

```
C:\Users\DDevienne>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.3.1 2014-02-11 14:52:19
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table parent (sn text primary key, data text);
sqlite> create table child_int (sn integer references parent(sn), data text, unique(sn));
sqlite> create table child_txt (sn text    references parent(sn), data text, unique(sn));
sqlite> insert into parent values ('x', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('z', '3');
sqlite> insert into child_int values ('x', 'one'), ('y', 'two'), ('z', 'three');
sqlite> insert into child_txt values ('x', 'one'), ('y', 'two'), ('z', 'three');
sqlite> select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_int c on p.sn = c.sn where p.sn = 'y';
2|two
sqlite> select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_int c on p.sn = c.sn where c.sn = 'y';
2|two
sqlite> select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_txt c on p.sn = c.sn where p.sn = 'y';
2|two
sqlite> select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_txt c on p.sn = c.sn where c.sn = 'y';
2|two
sqlite> explain query plan select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_int c on p.sn = c.sn where p.sn = 'y';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE parent AS p USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_parent_1 (sn=?)
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE child_int AS c USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_child_int_1 (sn=?)
sqlite> explain query plan select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_int c on p.sn = c.sn where c.sn = 'y';
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE child_int AS c USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_child_int_1 (sn=?)
0|1|0|SCAN TABLE parent AS p
sqlite> explain query plan select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_txt c on p.sn = c.sn where p.sn = 'y';
0|0|1|SEARCH TABLE child_txt AS c USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_child_txt_1 (sn=?)
0|1|0|SEARCH TABLE parent AS p USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_parent_1 (sn=?)
sqlite> explain query plan select p.data, c.data from parent p, child_txt c on p.sn = c.sn where c.sn = 'y';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE parent AS p USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_parent_1 (sn=?)
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE child_txt AS c USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_child_txt_1 (sn=?)
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks also for your reply on the sqlite mailing list :) I'll be interested to see if someone there can explain the asymmetry!